# How can I save .doc or .docx as PDF with VBA overwitring?

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

I have a code that I use in Access to save all .docx in a folder as .pdf. The problem is: when there already exists a file .docx as .pdf, the code fails and I don't know why it doesn't save the .docx as .pdf overwriting the pdf previous. How can I do that with my actual code?

My actual code is:

```
Private Sub Generate_PDFs_Click()

    Dim directory As String
    Dim fldr As Object
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select folder with Word files to export to PDF"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
        directory = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
  
    Dim fso, newFile, Folder, files, folders
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Folder = fso.GetFolder(directory)
    Set files = Folder.files
    
    
    For Each file In files
        
        If file.path Like "*.docx*" Then
            newName = Replace(file.path, ".docx", ".pdf")
            newName = Replace(newName, ".doc", ".pdf")
            
            
            'Debug.Print file.Path
            Documents.Open FileName:=file.path, _
                ConfirmConversions:=False, _
                ReadOnly:=False, _
                AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
                PasswordDocument:="", _
                PasswordTemplate:="", _
                Revert:=False, _
                WritePasswordDocument:="", _
                WritePasswordTemplate:="", _
                Format:= _
                wdOpenFormatAuto, _
                XMLTransform:=""
                
            
                
            ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=newName, _
                ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
                OpenAfterExport:=False, _
                OptimizeFor:= _
                wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
                Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
                From:=1, To:=1, _
                Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
                IncludeDocProps:=True, _
                KeepIRM:=True, _
                CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, _
                DocStructureTags:=True, _
                BitmapMissingFonts:=True, _
                UseISO19005_1:=False
            ActiveDocument.Close
            End If
            
        If file.path Like "*.dwg*" Then
            MsgBox "Isso ainda não foi feito"
            End If

        Next
      
End Sub
```

Comment: See, for example: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1317717-vba-required-to-convert-word-to-pdf-for-folders-and-subfolders.html. No need for fso if you're not processing sub-folders as well.

Answer (score 0):

Before running save, enter the following line, so Access will not prompt you, to overwrite your file if it already exists,
`Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

and then after saving to turn the DisplayAlerts back on,
`Application.DisplayAlerts = True`